# Two OnEdit functions not working together

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got two `onEdit()` function scrips on a Google spreadsheet. But seems like one function is working at a time.

First function is a script to color all Rows, and second one is date function for adding dates on 2 cells based on column edit.

Here  are the scripts.

```js
function colorAll() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 4;
  var endRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
    colorRow(r);
  }
}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
function colorRow(r)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(r, 1, 1, 32);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = data[0];
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  if(row[14] === ""){
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
    dataRange.setFontColor("#000000");
  }
  else if(row[14] === "BEING USED") {
    dataRange.setBackgroundRGB(150, 185, 255);
    dataRange.setFontColor("#004BE1");
  }
}
function onEdit(event)
{
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  if (r >= 2) {
    colorRow(r);
  }
}

function onOpen(){
  colorAll();
```

And the second function.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 19 || col == 21) {
    var adjacentCell = aCell.offset(0, 1);  
    var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 
      "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    adjacentCell.setValue(newDate);
  }
}
```

The date function is working but the `colorRow` function is not, if I remove the date script then the `colorRow` will work.

Can any one point me in the right direction? Seems like I am missing something

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Barry Smith's comment about "two functions with same name" is right; only the second would execute in that case.

You can have just one spreadsheet-contained function named `onEdit()`. If you want to use another function as an `onEdit` trigger, you need to set it up as an *installable* trigger.

You can use the dialog from `Resources -> Current Project's Triggers` to install the second trigger.

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, you could have just one `onEdit()` simple trigger, but have it call the "sub-trigger" functions, passing the event object `e` to each of them.

Background: [Guide to Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/).

Comment: Wow ! Thanks Mogsdad, It worked, I didn't know about adding an extra trigger after renaming the onedit. Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding, but it looks like you have two different functions with the exact same name. This can't happen, because the second one is basically overwriting the first one. Give the different names and it should work.

Comment: Hi, I have tried different names as well, there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

Found a very simple solution for this, just add the below to the start of your script:

```js
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1(e);
  onEdit2(e)
}
```

I rename my onEdit accordingly e.g. instead of onEdit1(e) I'll use hideRow(e) or whatever is relevant.

Here's a full code using three onEdit functions (automatically adding time to an edited cell, auto hiding a row when using a tick box and auto inserting a row):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  autoTime(e);
  hideRow(e)
}

function autoTime(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1") {
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if (r.getColumn() == 2) {
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      if (nextCell.getValue() === '')
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}

function hideRow(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(e.range.rowStart);
}

function insertRow(e) {
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (e.range.getRow() > lastRow - 5)
    sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow - 1);
}
```