# Timestamp Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

Ok -- So I've been stumped for quite some time now and am seeking help to what should be a super easy problem...  I have 3 different Sheets within a Google Sheets file...  On each of the sheets I want to have one cell which basically creates a TimeStamp when another cell is modified.

So I know I am close as with copy/paste between what I've found here I can have this working for 1 of the 3 sheets (the last one listed) but for can't figure out how to get it working on all the sheets.

Please help!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyZNX.png)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var cols = [1];
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'OFFERS' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(typeof e.value !== 'object' ? new Date() : null)
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var cols = [1];
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'BIDS' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(typeof e.value !== 'object' ? new Date() : null)
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var cols = [1];
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'LEADS' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) == -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(typeof e.value !== 'object' ? new Date() : null)
}
```

Comment: You can only have a single function with any given name. Consider using an `if-else if` logic flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two OnEdit functions not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030085/two-onedit-functions-not-working-together)

Comment: Also see: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/D8CTGklLUwU;context-place=forum/docs